# To avoid auto generated Query string value in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, html.actionlink

I was trying to add a css class to anchor but while rendering to html the href attribute has query string with value 4. The controller name "Home" length is appended to href link. If I remove the css class it's working fine. Ho to avoid the autogenerated query string value.

**Razor Code:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Application", "CreateApplication", "Home", new {@class="link"});
```

**Rendered html is :**

```
<a href="/Account/CreateApplication?Length=4" class="link">Create Application</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the controller name as a parameter you can use the following signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So, you should use it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Application", "CreateApplication", "Home", null, new { @class = "link" });
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature you're calling is

```
ActionLink(string text, string actionName, object rotueValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

In particular, the third parameter is not a controller name, but an object of parameters to build the route from.

You can pass `new { controller = "..." }`