# Why do some parameters get added using pre-defined routes while others are placed in a query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, url-parameters

I am trying to pass two pieces of information from one view to another.  The URL that is created from the action link uses a query string instead of placing the parameters in the URL using the routes defined in the RouteConfig file.

Route Configurations

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserDetail",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{system}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "UserDetails", system = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Search",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchText}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", searchText = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Search Results View

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            @foreach (DataColumn _col in Model.Columns)
            { 
                <td>@_col.ColumnName</td>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow _row in Model.Rows) 
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("View", "UserDetails", "Search", new { system = _row["System"], id = _row["UserID"] }, null);
                </td>
                @foreach (DataColumn _col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <td>@_row[_col.ColumnName]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The following line always creates a URL that uses a query string...

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "UserDetails", "Search", new { system = _row["System"], id = _row["UserID"] }, null);
```

What is created:

```
http://localhost:54137/Search/UserDetails/91605?system=SP
```

What I want:

```
http://localhost:54137/Search/UserDetails/SP/91605
```

Here is the controller for the views I am using.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UserDetails(string system, int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || system == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(system))
        {
            ViewBag.SearchResult = "No User ID was selected";
        }
        else 
        {
            ViewBag.SearchResult = "You searched for User ID: " + id + " in the " + system + " system";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please see the following link at stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640536/to-avoid-auto-generated-query-string-value-in-actionlink

Comment: According to that link, I want to change <@Html.ActionLink("View", "UserDetails", "Search", new { system = _row["System"], id = _row["UserID"] }, null)> to <@Html.ActionLink("View", "UserDetails", "Search", null, new { system = _row["System"], id = _row["UserID"] })>.  That removes all the parameters from the link that is created because it is using the wrong signature.  It creates a link like the following: http://localhost:54137/Search/UserDetails/.  I think this link is a different issue.  If not, please explain further.

Comment: My bad, had a brain fart on that one. You are in essence looking for attribute routing which you probably need to do something like @Html.ActionLink("View", "UserDetails", "Search/" + _row["system"] "/" + _row["UserId"]).

Comment: I'm sure that would work fine, but why does the URL get rendered to this (http://localhost:54137/Search/UserDetails/91605?system=SP) when using the syntax I had?  It seems as though it should accept multiple parameters and achieve a similar result. I feel like if the ActionLink method can put one parameter in the URL, why can't it put two? Thanks for your help though.  I will use this strategy until I can find a better way...

Comment: It certainly looks like a limitation of ActionLink itself. Personally never ran into it but I do like the cleaner look of Attribute Routing.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink` is going up to down on your route table and your 2nd route will never get used. In order to specify a route you want to use for the link, use `@Html.RouteLink()` instead.

Comment: @tweray - thanks for the helpful comment! I chose to re-order the routes as mentioned below, but it's good to know that I can specify which route to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be because the routing engine simply goes through your route registrations in the order you've registered them. The first one that seems to match will be picked. Therefore, you need to re-arrange the order of which you register your routes, starting with the most specific ones.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserDetail",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{system}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "UserDetails", system = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Search",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchText}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", searchText = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something trivial... That took care of it! Thanks for the quick response!